# How to make Button only mouse clickable (not by Enter)

Tags: wpf

I have a `Button` WPF control, and I **don't want** user pressing the button with an **Enter key**. I want to make it possible to click a button **only with a mouse click**.

Is it possible in WPF?

Comment: What is the point? Someone will probably come a long and help you figure this out... but *why*? Why do developers insist on doing things like this to cripple a UI or make it otherwise unusable from a keyboard?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The button sometimes accidentally picks up when pressing Enter somewhere else. I don't want to cripple the UX of people when not necessary.

Comment: Fair enough. We see a lot of questions here of people trying to make really strange UIs. Glad to see you've got  UX in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the button's Focusable Property to False.